# Form fields are not being validated through DTO with @Valid and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, validation, thymeleaf

This seems to be a very common case of form validation. I have read through many other stackoverflow questions and articles and I can't find where my problem lies.

## What did I try

### Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'nathanLively'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
//  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
//  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'  // :3.0.5
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

### DTO

#### UserAlignmentDTO

```
package nathanLively.subAlignerjava.DTO;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.Enums.UnitsEnum;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.PreAlignment;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.Speaker;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.UserAlignment;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.UserAlignmentSource;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class UserAlignmentDTO {

    private UnitsEnum units;

    @Builder.Default
    private List<UserAlignmentSourceDTO2> userAlignmentSources = new ArrayList<>();

    // Constructor
    public UserAlignmentDTO(PreAlignment preAlignment) {
        int numberOfPreAlignmentSources = preAlignment.getPreAlignmentSources().size();
        this.userAlignmentSources = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPreAlignmentSources; i++) {
            UserAlignmentSourceDTO2 userAlignmentSourceDTO2 = UserAlignmentSourceDTO2.builder()
                    .modelName(preAlignment.getPreAlignmentSources().get(i).getSpeaker().getSpeakerModel().getName())
                    .build();
            this.userAlignmentSources.add(userAlignmentSourceDTO2);
        }
    }

    // Methods
    public UserAlignment toUserAlignment(PreAlignment preAlignment) {
        ArrayList<UserAlignmentSource> userAlignmentSourceList = userAlignmentSources.stream()
                .map(UserAlignmentSourceDTO2::toUserAlignmentSource)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

        UserAlignment userAlignment = UserAlignment.builder()
                .preAlignment(preAlignment)
                .userAlignmentSources(userAlignmentSourceList)
                .distanceUnit(units)
                .build();

        for (UserAlignmentSource userAlignmentSource : userAlignmentSourceList) {
            userAlignmentSource.setUserAlignment(userAlignment);
        }

        return userAlignment;
    }
}
```

#### UserAlignmentSourceDTO2

```
package nathanLively.subAlignerjava.DTO;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.Min;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Positive;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.Enums.UnitsEnum;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.PreAlignment;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.PreAlignmentSource;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.Speaker;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.UserAlignmentSource;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class UserAlignmentSourceDTO2 {

    private String modelName;

    @Min(message = "The minimum is 1.", value = 1)
    @NotNull(message = "The count must not be null.")
    private Integer count;

    @NotNull(message = "The distance must not be null.")
    @Positive(message = "The distance should be positive.")
    private Float distance;

    public UserAlignmentSource toUserAlignmentSource() {

        return UserAlignmentSource.builder()
                .count(count)
                .distance(distance)
                .build();
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
package nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Controllers;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.DTO.UserAlignmentDTO;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.Enums.UnitsEnum;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.PreAlignment;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Models.UserAlignment;
import nathanLively.subAlignerjava.Services.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/align")
public class AlignController {
    
    private final UserAlignmentService userAlignmentService;
    private final PreAlignmentService preAlignmentService;

// Create UserAlignment and calculate result
    @PostMapping("/calculate/{id}")
    public String calculateUserAlignment(@PathVariable("id") Long preAlignmentId,
                                         @Valid @ModelAttribute("userAlignmentDTO") UserAlignmentDTO userAlignmentDTO,
                                         BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        // Form validation
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "user-alignment";
        }

        // Find pre-alignment
        PreAlignment preAlignment = preAlignmentService.findById(preAlignmentId);

        // Calculate result and add to model
        UserAlignment UserAlignmentResult = userAlignmentService.calculateResultAndSave(preAlignment, userAlignmentDTO);
        model.addAttribute("userAlignment", UserAlignmentResult);

        // Show UserAlignment unit because I'm not sure how to get it out of the userAlignment object
        model.addAttribute("unit", UserAlignmentResult.getDistanceUnit().getAbbreviation());

        return "result";
    }
}
```

### Thymeleaf template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{layout/layout}"
      th:with="activeMenuItem='align'"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User Alignment</title>
</head>
<body>
<div layout:fragment="page-content">
    <h1>User-Alignment</h1>
    <form id="source-form"
          th:object="${userAlignmentDTO}"
          th:action="@{/align/calculate/{id}(id=${preAlignment.id})}"
          method="post">
        <th:block th:each="source,iter : *{userAlignmentSources}">
            <label th:text="${iter.index + 1} + '.'"></label>
            <label>Total [[${source.modelName}]] in array:</label>
            <input type="number"
                   th:field="*{userAlignmentSources[__${iter.index}__].count}">
            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('userAlignmentSources[__${iter.index}__].count')}"
               th:text="${#strings.listJoin(#fields.errors('userAlignmentSources[__${iter.index}__].count'), ', ')}"></p>
            <label>Distance from [[${source.modelName}]] to FOH:</label>
            <input type="number"
                   th:field="*{userAlignmentSources[__${iter.index}__].distance}">
            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('userAlignmentSources[__${iter.index}__].distance')}"
               th:text="${#strings.listJoin(#fields.errors('userAlignmentSources[__${iter.index}__].distance'), ', ')}"></p>
        </th:block>
        <label>Unit</label>
        <select th:field="*{units}">
            <option th:each="unit : ${units}"
                    th:text="${unit.fullName}"
                    th:value="${unit}">meters
            </option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Align</button>
    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## What I was expecting

With any of the specified field errors, I expect the bindingResult to have more than zero errors and for the form to be reloaded with the error messages visible. This never happens. The bindingResult is always empty and the application attempts to persist the form data, which crashes because of the database validation.

Comment: Which Spring version are you using and make sure you have `hibernate-validator` on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum . I have version '3.0.4'. I thought maybe  hibernate-validator was missing, but I asked chatGPT about that last night:

> Additionally, you have added the hibernate-validator dependency, but it is commented out. This is not necessary for basic validation functionality in Spring MVC, as the spring-boot-starter-validation dependency should provide all the necessary validation functionality. If you require advanced validation features like custom validators or programmatic validation, you may need to include the hibernate-validator dependency and additional configuration.

Comment: You are nowhere mentioning that you are using Spring BOot (just spring). Please provide your dependencies (you are using Spring Boot 3.0.4 which uses Spring 6). So again please add your dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a nested object, you need to add an `@Valid` annotation in the "parent" as well. Something like this should work:

```
public class UserAlignmentDTO {

    private UnitsEnum units;

    @Builder.Default
    private List<@Valid UserAlignmentSourceDTO2> userAlignmentSources = new ArrayList<>();
```

Notice the extra `@Valid` in the generic list declaration.

Comment: Thanks Wim! Please feel free to use all of my questions for the next edition of your book! :)